# Flash / AS : animation when SWF is called

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have 2737 buttons calling as many SWF (all on the same level, replacing each other when loaded).

I'd like to add a loading animation in my root file that would run every time an url is called or a SWF is loading. is it possible?

I gave up on the idea of incorporating a percentage pre-loader as I would have to add code on all the 2737 buttons... right?

FIY, this is a 2001 CD-Rom project I want to bring back online, so no pre-loader was required then.

any help is greatly appreciated!

*here's an example of one of the many buttons:*

```
on (release) {
loadMovieNum("04.12.01.swf", 1);}
```

Comment: It's ActionScript 1/2, not 3.

Comment: ok edited the title. is it possible to do or not?

Comment: Also remove **actionscript-3** tag. Then, just FYI, AS1 is 14 years as obsolete, thus, albeit it is not impossible to do the thing you want, I don't really remember the details, AS1 is very unstraightforward and you will need to learn how the event handlers work there. Probably, something like that (loading images or SWFs are basically the same thing): https://forums.adobe.com/thread/767711